# Why and What is meaning of adding *dispatch* variable to the *dependency array* for useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm going through one of ReactJS Project's Source code and got to see that **dispatch** variable is added to the dependency array of useEffect. I know about adding **useState()** variables, but this is new to me that why and what is need, meaning of adding **dispatch**.

This is my Code, where I'm stuck:-
[image]

I removed **dispatch** from deps. array but nothing seems change to me.

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch` never changes, so it is technically not necessary to add it to dependency arrays. The only issue is that ESLint does not know that, so it will complain about a missing dependency. The easiest way to get rid of that warning is to add it to the dependency array anyway. It doesn't hurt to have a useless dependency, but missing a real dependency can very easily create bugs, so silencing ESLint by adding useless dependencies is much better than ignoring the warning altogether.